# How to get good performance on the gfx card with images larger than the max texture size?

Tags: image, performance, opengl, sdl-2, frame-rate

At work, I work with very large images.
I currently do my rendering via SDL2.
The max texture size on the graphics card my machine uses is 8192x8192.
Because my data sets are larger than what will fit in a single texture, I split my image into multiple textures after it is loaded, and tile them.
However, I have found that this comes at a very steep cost. Rendering only 4 textures around 5K by 5K (pixels) each completely tanks the framerate!

Conventional wisdom tells me that the fewer texture swaps the better, but with such large images I've found myself between a rock and a hard place.

One thing I've considered is that perhaps if I were to chunck the images up into many small textures, I could take advantage of culling which would hopefully be a net win. But there's a big problem with that approach - I need to be able to zoom out.

Another option would be to down scale the images. This seems promising as the analysis I am doing on the images do not require the high resolution that the images provide.

I know that OpenGL has mipmapping, but I am inexperienced with OpenGL and am weary of diving into it for a work project. I am not aware of a good way to downscale the images within the confines of SDL2, and for reasons specific to the work I am doing, scaling the images down offline (before I load them) is not appealing.

What is the best approach for me to get the highest framerate in this situation?

Comment: Take a look at the function `SDL_BlitScaled`.

Comment: Mipmapping is not a lot of work to set up. What GL version are you using?

Comment: What target resolution are you rendering _to_? In your scenario, I would expect the texture fill rate / memory bandwidth the limiting factor, not just 4 texture switches per frame. If you want to avoid these, you can also stuff all the tiles into a single array texture, btw. But I really advice to benchmark/profile first before trying to optimize.

Comment: @beerboy SDL_BlitScaled is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @derhass Variable, as the window is resizable. I agree! I conceptually thought of the texture fill rate as well as the texture switch as one functional unit, so to speak. The memory bandwidth is definitely the limiting factor here. I was unaware of array textures, had to look that up, and that is really awesome to know about. SDL_BlitScaled is the best option for this project I feel, but I'm really happy you shared that tip!